# I have a desktop Windows PC and MacBook Pro. How do I use the microphone on my Mac for my Windows PC?

Tags: windows, mac, audio, microphone

I currently do not have a microphone, and I've tried using my phone as a microphone for my PC but the audio quality is really bad. I do have an early-2011 MacBook Pro with a good built-in microphone. Is there a way I can use the microphone on my mac as a microphone input source for my Windows PC?

I'm new to this forum by the way, so I don't know if I'm posting in the right place.

Thanks!

Comment: Do not post continuing comments as answers. It may be a good idea to read the Help section to learn how SuperUser works.

Comment: Also, have you researched this any? What have you learned so far? Have you tried one or another solution?